# Elasticsearch Query - How to aggregate timestamps and filter by term?

Tags: jquery, json, elasticsearch, kibana

I have a working filter query:

```
{
  "filter": {
    "and": [{
      "range": {
        "timestamp": {
          "gte": "2015-05-07T12:04:30Z"
          "lte": "2015-08-07T12:04:30Z"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "term": {
        "in_context.course_id": "1234567"
      }
    }]
  },
  "fields": ["timestamp"]
}
```

which returns the timestamp of every event in the last three months.
But there are ~ 1 million timestamps returned which makes the response too large, so I would like to aggregate the results and get the sum of documents per day.

I found this snippet that uses a date histogram:

```
{
    "aggs" : {
        "histo1" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "timestamp",
                "interval" : "day"
            },
            "aggs" : {
                "price_stats" : {
                    "stats" : {
                        "field" : "price"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

which is exactly what I need, but I can't figure out how to incorporate it into my original query with the term filter! Would be really glad for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do it like this by adding the `aggs` part at the top level in your query. Note that I wrapped your `filter` into a `filtered` query.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "range": {
              "timestamp": {
                "gte": "2015-05-07T12:04:30Z",
                "lte": "2015-08-07T12:04:30Z"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "term": {
              "in_context.course_id": "1234567"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "histo1": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "interval": "day"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice! This actually seems to work, but I don't need the "price"-related stuff in the sub-aggregations, that was just taken from the snippet I found.

Comment: But one question: the `fields` parameter here isn't really useful, right? Since I'm only interested in the aggregations, I think I could simply replace it with a `size: 0`, couldn't I?

Comment: Correct, no `fields` and add `"size": 0`, I've edited my answer

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm, so the idea is to use a filtered query. Can you explain why? Is it also possible with filters only?

Comment: `filter` as a top level element has been renamed to `post_filter`, which you can use too. See [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_search_requests.html) for detailed info.

Comment: For others that are looking at this type of functionality, you need to be a bit careful here, as this method won't return empty buckets.
i.e. If you want empties (as you very well might for @timestamp intervals - e.g. you're graphing it), specify "min_doc_count": 0, but...this still won't return empty buckets as the aggs only operate within the bounds of the query, so you need to also specify:
"extended_bounds": {
 "min": "2015-05-07T12:04:30Z",
 "max": "2015-08-07T12:04:30Z"
}
This ensures the agg filter will include the full range.